# Need to apply indention styles for titles like: 1 - 1.1 - 1.1.1

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm newbie to MS-Word 2010. I have a Word document already made, but contains titles that need to apply styles like:

```
 3.Third Title

   3.1 My sub title number three point one

      3.1.1 My sub title number three point one point one
```

My problem is that those titles have no indent, all of them start from first left column like:

```
3.Third Title

3.1 My sub title number three point one

3.1.1 My sub title number three point one point one
```

I need to apply style starting from title number 3 and apply it in once for all my titles. How could I do it?

Comment: Is this for a table of contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the built-in list styles provides the exact numbering you want along with indentation for each level (see the list style with the yellow border below). Simply highlight your paragraphs and apply it. To increase the level of a paragraph click inside the numbering and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

[image]